# DATE PBM IN POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, grails

```
SELECT SUM(salesamt) from t0006.retailsummary WHERE perioddate between '2012-11-2' and '2013-12-31';
```

its works but I want (using date variable,I assigned `startdate=2012-11-1` like that)

```
SELECT SUM(salesamt) from t0006.retailsummary WHERE perioddate between startdate and enddate;
```

its not working

Comment: convert it to `datetime`

Comment: you wont give date ,you use only table field name?

Comment: is the grails tag here relevant?  if yes, please also show the code, you are calling the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
\set startdate '\'' 2012-11-02 '\''
\set enddate '\'' 2013-12-31 '\''
SELECT SUM(salesamt) from t0006.retailsummary WHERE perioddate between :startdate and :enddate;
```